# How to access resolved date within root scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app I have states that fetch various resources from server using `resolve` clause.

I also have a **global** controller that need access to these resources. For example, consider a breadcrumb that needs to show some data of these resource.

How can I access these resources from the global controller? Even if I have the state object at hand, I couldn't figure how to extract the resolved properties.

EDIT: I'm using [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site) package for routing.

Comment: My first thought is to use service for proper two way databinding, but to tell you more I'd have to see your code and logic in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to add a resolve key that depends on the required data (see `breadcrumb` in code below). When the function of this key is invoked, we can be assured that our data `item` is ready for use. Then we put it on the state (`data` property).

```
.state('some.item.detail.state', {
  url: '/:itemId',
  resolve: {
    item: function($stateParams, MyServerResource) { 
            return MyServerResource.get({itemId: $stateParams.itemId}).$promise;
          },
    breadcrumb: function(item) {
                  this.data = item;
                }
  },
  templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
}
```

To consume the data in the global controller, we simple examine `$state.current.data`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have something like this:

```
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    resolve: {data: someDataFetcher}
  })
```

And you need to access the data in a global controller. I would have to see a code example to perfectly understand what you want, but I would suggest using a shared service.

```
function HomeCtrl (data, myDataService) {
  myDataService.data = data;
}

function GlobalCtrl (myDataService) {
  myDataService.data // => The data
}
```

A service has only one instance so it is easy to use that to share state and resources across controllers.

Hope this helps.

**update**:

Create a resolve closure:

```
var myResolveClosure = function (resolver) {
    // Return a wrapper around the resolver
    return function (globalController, $q) { 
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      resolver($q).then(function (data) {
        globalController.addData(data);
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).catch(function () {
        deferred.reject();
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
}

  .when('/', {
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    resolve: {
     data: myResolveClosure(function ($q) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       // do something and resolve with the data
       return deferred.promise;
     })
    }
  })
```

So basically you pass in the specific resolver you need to fetch that data. The "myResolveClosure" will wrap a a function around the resolver, passing in $q to the specific resolver to do some fetching. It will then take the data resolved from the specific resolver and pass it into the global controller, then resolve itself so that any controller you specified also will get the data.

Hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: Yes, you have described the problem correctly, thank you. One exception, I'm using ui-route instead of ng-route, but the concept is the same. With your solution I now depend on a very specific controller, `HomeCtrl`. What if I have 20 states and 3 views per each? Each controller will have to notify the global service with data. That's a lot of code repetition.

Comment: You could use a closure to wrap a function around the specific resolver. The outer function would wait for the specific resolver to resolve, then add the data to the global controller, then resolve itself with the same data. See the update :-)

Comment: This might work, but it's quite complex. For ng-route it might be the only way, I don't know. But since I use ui-route I found a way to do this in one line of code. In your example, it's like adding additional key to `resolve` that depends on `data`, and then setting the route `data` property (or any other private property) to the resolved value.